# How can I use machine.config settings in the NLog.config

Tags: c#, nlog, machine.config

Is it possible to use a machine.config setting inside the Nlog.config?

Example

```
       <nlog>
          ...
          <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" 
keepConnection="true" dbDatabase="xxx" 
dbHost="**MACHINE_CONFIG_SETTING**" 
commandType="StoredProcedure"  dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient" dbUserName="**MACHINE_CONFIG_SETTING**"
 dbPassword="**MACHINE_CONFIG_SETTING**" 
  connectionString="**MACHINE_CONFIG_SETTING**"
          commandText="stored_proc">
    </nlog>
```

We have the dbhost name and dbUsername in the machine config so I don't really want to duplicate that information in the Nlog config.
I don't want to put the whole of the Nlog configuration in the machine config if I can help it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible, but you can't overwrite it partly.

You can also use [`<include file="${basedir}/${machinename}.config"/>`](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#include-files) for reuse, which is a bit more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I actually used the LogManager.Configuration to get the target and cast it to database target in my code and then the System.Configuration to get config I needed from the machine config.  Worked a treat